# Perl script to start/stop windows service

Tags: windows, perl

Here is the script for checking status of windows services and if they are in stop state, it will start the service. I can able to get the status of service, but can't able to start services.
please help and let me know what I need to do.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Win32::Service;
use strict;

sub checkService();
sub getDate();
sub getTime();
sub logEvent();

my @timeInfo = localtime(time);
my $serviceName = "TapiSrv";
my $currentDate = getDate();
my $currentTime = getTime();
my %status;
my %status_code = (1 => 'not running',
               2 => 'start pending',
               3 => 'stop pending',
               4 => 'running',
               5 => 'resume pending',
               6 => 'pause pending',
               7 => 'paused');

checkService();

########
# SUBS
########


sub checkService() {
my $startCounter = 0;

Win32::Service::GetStatus('', $serviceName,  \%status);

if($status{"CurrentState"} eq '4') {
    # Log the event
    &logEvent("$currentTime:  $serviceName is running\n");
} elsif($status{"CurrentState"} eq '1') {

    Win32::Service::StartService('', $serviceName);
    }       
    while($startCounter < 3) {
        sleep(5);

        Win32::Service::GetStatus('', $serviceName,  \%status);

        if($status{"CurrentState"} eq '2') {
            $startCounter++;
        } else {
            $startCounter = 3;
        }
    }

    if($startCounter == 3) {
        &logEvent("$currentTime:  Unable to start $serviceName in $startCounter attempts\n");
    } else {
        &logEvent("$currentTime:  Started $serviceName in $startCounter attempts\n");
    }
}

sub getDate() {
my $year = $timeInfo[5] + 1900;
my $month = $timeInfo[4] + 1;
my $day = $timeInfo[3];
return sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day);
} 

sub getTime() {
my $hour = $timeInfo[2];
my $min = $timeInfo[1];
my $sec = $timeInfo[0];
return sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hour, $min, $sec);
}

sub logEvent() {
# Log the event
open(OUT, ">> C:/servicestatus/$currentDate.txt");
print OUT "$_[0]";
close(OUT);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon some comments below (including some nice points by @Ron Bergin), I'm revising this post to show code that works for me (Windows 8.1, ActivePerl 5.16).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;
use Win32::Service;

my $currentDate = getDate();
my %status;
my %status_code = (
  Stopped => 1,
  StartPending => 2,
  StopPending => 3,
  Running => 4,
  ResumePending => 5,
  PausePending => 6,
  Paused => 7
);

checkService("Apple Mobile Device");

########
# SUBS
########

sub checkService {
  my $serviceName = shift || die "No arg passed";
  my $startCounter = 1;
  Win32::Service::GetStatus('', $serviceName, \%status);
  if ($status{"CurrentState"} eq $status_code{Running}) {
    logEvent("$serviceName is running\n");
  }
  elsif ($status{"CurrentState"} eq $status_code{'Stopped'}) {
    my $maxAttempts = 3;
    while ($startCounter <= $maxAttempts) {
      logEvent("Attempting to start $serviceName");
      Win32::Service::StartService('', $serviceName);
      sleep(5);
      Win32::Service::GetStatus('', $serviceName, \%status);
      if ($status{"CurrentState"} eq $status_code{Running}) {
        logEvent("Started $serviceName in $startCounter attempts\n");
        last;
      }
      $startCounter++;
    }

    if ($startCounter eq $maxAttempts) {
      logEvent("Unable to start $serviceName in $startCounter attempts\n");
    }
  }
}

sub getDate {
  my @timeInfo    = localtime(time);
  my $year  = $timeInfo[5] + 1900;
  my $month = $timeInfo[4] + 1;
  my $day   = $timeInfo[3];
  return sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day);
}

sub logEvent {
  my $msg = strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime) . ": $_[0]\n";
  print "$msg";
  open(OUT, ">> C:/servicestatus/$currentDate.txt");
  print OUT "$msg";
  close(OUT);
}
```

Running this NOT as an admin, gives output like this:

```
14:11:30: Attempting to start Apple Mobile Device
14:11:35: Attempting to start Apple Mobile Device
14:11:40: Attempting to start Apple Mobile Device
```

Running as an admin looks like this:

```
14:14:29: Attempting to start Apple Mobile Device
14:14:34: Started Apple Mobile Device in 1 attempts
```

Comment: What "open paren"? I don't see any open paren after the `StartService` call in the question code (maybe the question got edited).

Comment: Sorry, the "close paren"!  Right before the WHILE loop.

Comment: Not seeing a close paren (`)`) there either. There's a closing curly bracket / brace (`}`) which indeed may need to move somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the brace.  Don't know what I was thinking!  But your code worked for me when I moved that, added the extra sleep.  Need to run as admin though, maybe that's it?

Comment: I think the logic and coding style is very questionable.(1) Needlessly pre-declaring the subs.  (2) Using [emplty] prototypes  (3) Vars declared in the wrong scope.  Since they are only used inside the sub, then that's were they should be declared  (4) It would be cleaner and easier to use strftime() instead of rolling you own getDate() and getTime() functions. (5) Using eq instead of == for numerical equality test. (6) Using & when calling subs.  (7) Inconsistent and missing indentation. (8) Failing to test the return value of the GetStatus() and StartService() calls.

Comment: hi jimtut - the parenthesis which you mentioned is in correct place. That parenthesis which was right before while loop is for the elsif condition. I can't find any mistake there. can you please brief which part you are referring to. So that it will be helpful for me.

Comment: If you don't move the closing brace, then it's closing out the first if/then/elsif block.  This means that no matter which branch of that first if/then/elsif block the code follows, everything after this misplaced brace gets executed.  So, if you're supposed to follow the "service is running" branch of that block, after you call logEvent(), you jump to the rest of the code, which attempts to START the (already running) service.

Comment: Jim's adjusted version is much better, but could still be improved.  I left out about a half dozen other points in my prior post but instead of listing them now, I'll address them in my suggested version.  I can't do that now but in a couple hours when I have free time, I post some code.

Answer (score 1):

One major problem I have with this Win32::Service module is that it returns undef on failure **BUT** doesn't set $! so finding out why it failed is more work.  I have not done any testing in retrieving that error, but it's probably a call to one of the functions in the Win32 module.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Win32::Service qw(StartService GetStatus GetServices);

my $service = shift || 'Apple Mobile Device';
check_service($service);
exit;

###############################################################################

sub check_service {
    my $service = shift;
    my %status_code = (
        Stopped       => 1,
        StartPending  => 2,
        StopPending   => 3,
        Running       => 4,
        ResumePending => 5,
        PausePending  => 6,
        Paused        => 7
    );
    my (%status, %services);

    GetServices('', \%services) or do {
        log_event('Failed to retieve list of services');
        exit;
    };
    %services = reverse %services;

    if (! exists $services{$service}) {
        log_event("'$service' is not a configured Windows service");
        exit;
    }

    if (GetStatus('', $service, \%status)) {
        if ($status{"CurrentState"} eq $status_code{Running} ) {
            log_event("$service is running");
        }
        elsif ( $status{"CurrentState"} eq $status_code{'Stopped'} ) {
            ATTEMPT: for (1..3) {
                log_event("Attempting to start '$service'");
                if (StartService('', $service)) {
                    sleep 5;
                    GetStatus('', $service, \%status);
                    if ($status{"CurrentState"} eq $status_code{Running}) {
                        log_event("Started '$service'");
                        last ATTEMPT;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    die "StartService() function failed";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        log_event("failed to retrieve the status of service '$service'");
        exit;
    }
    return;
}

sub log_event {

# Using one of the better loging modules such as Log::Log4perl
# would be a much better and more robust logging mechanism

    my $msg = shift;
    my $timestamp = strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime);
    my $filename  = strftime("C:/servicestatus/%Y-%m-%d.txt", localtime);

    open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "failed to open '$filename' <$!>";
    say $fh "$timestamp: $msg";
    close $fh;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help jimtut & Ron Bergin .
But still I'm facing problem here, I have full administrative rights for the server where I'm executing this script. But I'm cant able to start the services. As mentioned by jimtut, just i'm getting the output which is showing under non administrative part.
To confirm I checked with my admin team and they confirmed that I'm having full admin privileges. Please help.

Comment: Did you try my version? It will probably output the "StartService() function failed" error message, as it did for me.  You could add the additional error handling that I mentioned to find out why it fails, but I'll point out the problem.  I discovered that it's a user rights issue.  I tested it on Win7 and even though I'm logged in with administrator rights, it would not restart the service unless/until I used the runas command to run it as the system level "Administrator", which is different from a regular user with elevated privileges.

Comment: Hi @RonBergin yes I tried your version and it is showing "StartService() function failed". Is there any other way that we can start/stop services after logging in as admin through program directly with out using the runas command ? Is it possible? What I need to do to get rid of this situation? please suggest

Comment: @jimtut can you please help me in this regard. When I'm calling Perl using Batch file, I could see Run as administrator option. But how come we can run Perl script directly as Admin? I didn't see any option to run as admin.

Comment: I usually open a DOS prompt as admin, and then type commands (like this) in that DOS window when I need to run things as an admin.  You can also create a BAT script that calls the Perl script, then create a Shortcut to the BAT and send the Run as Admin option on the Shortcut.  Not sure if you can create a shortcut to perl.exe like this too, but that might work too.